# Как в шаблон класса добавить обобщённое поле или метод, которые будут видны в его специализации

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Есть шаблонный класс, в котором есть набор полей и методов. При специализации этого класса доступ к этим полям и методом пропадает. Мне нужно сделать общую часть для всех специализаций, но так, чтобы пользователю создающему новую специализацию не пришлось добавлять её руками. т.е. мне нужно поведение, как при наследовании, но при специализации.

```
template <class T> class Foo {
public:
    // Обобщёная часть, которая должна быть во всех специализациях. 
    int some_field;
    void SomeMethod(int val) {
        some_field = val;
    };
};

// Но при специализации общая часть пропадает. 
template <> class Foo <std::string> {
public:
};

// При наследовании SomeMethod был бы доступен, а при специализации нет. 
template <class T>
void SomeFunction(Foo <T> val) {
    val.SomeMethod (5);
}

int main() {
    Foo<string> foo;
    SomeFunction(foo); // Соответственно внутри SomeFunction будет ошибка компиляции т.к. метода foo.SomeMethod не существует. 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сами пишете о наследовании - так, может, сделать наследованием? не вариант?

```
struct Generic
{
    int some_field;
    int SomeMethod(int val) {
        some_field = val;
        return 2;
    };
};

template <class T> class Foo: public Generic {
public:
};

// Но при специализации общая часть пропадает. 
template <> class Foo <std::string>: public Generic {
public:
};
```

Или даже `: public Generic` - слишком много?

Comment: Спасибо. Это хороший вариант. Если бы мы могли запретить пользователю Foo специализировать без соответствующего наследования или наследовать при каждой специализации автоматически, то это полностью решило бы мою проблему.

Comment: так ведь тут так и есть  _ все  специализации наследуют Generic

Comment: Если вы специализируете без наследования, попытка вызова/обращения к `Generic` приведет к ошибке - *разве это не то же самое, что и запрет такой специализации*? А если такого вызова/обращения нет в принципе - то и разницы никакой :)